# Is the Erevana the ship flying away from Jakku as Rey is left behind?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

Seems like they make sure we do not see who is dragging Rey along but still provide a clue with a long shot of the spaceship in the distance. I don't think we ever get an external view of the Erevana, the freighter Han is using after having to abandon the Falcon. Could it be the Han dropped Luke and Rey on Jakku and somehow had to leave the Falcon behind?

Comment: Han didn't bring the Falcon there; they explain the series of events (it was stolen multiple times) to get the Falcon to Jakku.

Comment: “Seems like they make sure we do not see who is dragging Rey along” — I think we see [Unkar Plutt](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Unkar_Plutt)’s chunky hand holding the little girl’s.

Comment: "I don't think we ever get an external view of the Erevana, the freighter Han is using after having to abandon the Falcon" - we do, when it captures Millenium Falcon in its hangar bay. I'll try to see if there's any match at some point

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We don't have any canon information on who left Rey on Jakku.

But most certainly, Han didn't "leave" Falcon behind there:

> “Look.” Taking a chance, Rey lowered her hands so she could spread her arms wide. “I don’t know all the details for sure. I’m not privy to Plutt’s private accounting. But talk says that Plutt stole this ship from the Irving Boys, who stole it from Ducain.”
>   “Who stole it from me!”
>   *(Alan Dean Foster's novelization)*

Comment: As a side comment - from what I gathered from Novelization, whoever said "I will come back for you" didn't even leave Rey on Jakku since it involved a **forest**, not a desert planet.

Comment: are you sure? at least in the film it was on a desert as far as I remember (in film the forest scene was just before or after that one scene and was indicatoin of the LATER forest scene that was going to happen)

Comment: @Thomas - not certain but I think so.

Comment: (had watched it 2 times and it was a desert scene.....even the four armed guy (or one of his species) held her back from trying to follow that one ship)

Answer (score 5):

### No. Absolutely not.

Even if we ignore the fact that the Eravana is a great big orbital whale of a ship, several dozen times larger than the Millennium Falcon then we have to contend with the fact that **it doesn't in any way resemble the ship that was seen in Rey's flashback**.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

I don't think it was that big. (The Evana is 6 or 7 times bigger than the Falcon, at least.) I thought it looked more like a T-47 airspeeder more than anything else: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/XLu-blZVTUs/maxresdefault.jpg but those are atmosphere-only craft, so what do I know.