# What kind of ship was flying away from Rey in her flashback?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

The ship flying away from Rey in her flashback of being left on Jakku looks like one of the ships in the group that takes her away when she is captured.

If so, and it is a First Order ship that dropped her off, this is an interesting Easter egg.

Comment: It was some kind of *space*ship.

Comment: Related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111720/is-the-erevana-the-ship-flying-away-from-jakku-as-rey-is-left-behind?rq=1 and http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/114054/who-owned-the-starship-that-abandoned-rey-on-jakku-in-her-vision?rq=1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<s>**We don't know.** As of April 4th 2016, there has been no in-canon description of the vessel matching any known ship found elsewhere in the Star Wars universe.</s>

The ship was called the ***Bestoon Legacy***. It was, we learn in *Rise of Skywalker*, owned by a Sith loyalist named Ochi. The film's [Visual Dictionary](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Rise_of_Skywalker:_The_Visual_Dictionary) identifies it as a **Subpro Corporation Model WTK-85A interstellar transport**

[image]

For the record, the ship doesn't match the First Order ships you're describing.

[image]

Comment: It looks like you're right. Chalk this up to my crappy memory/screen.

Answer (score -2):

In the book 'Star Wars: Before the Awakening', Rey rebuilds a ghtroc 690 with the help of two friends, but they turn out to be traitors and fly the ship away. Rey could have seen it in the vision.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SFF! This answer would be greatly improved if you improve the relevant text from the book. Also probably worth checking ages to see if Rey was around the same age in the book and flashback.

Comment: This event happened many years after her parents left her